# Formset for MainClass<-ForeignKey<-OneToOneField?

Tags: python, django, formset

I need to process applications to an amateur sports event. An event has several distances/subclasses, each of them has some restrictions (age, etc).

My models are

```
class Event(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  # more fields

class Klass(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  capacity = models.IntegerField()
  event = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name="klasses")
  # more fields

class TeamRestrictions(models.Model):
  age_min = models.IntegerField()
  age_max = models.IntegerField()
  klass = models.OneToOneField(TeamRestrictions, related_name='restrict')
  # more fields
```

I want to have a single page where a user creates a new event: names it, adds several subclasses into it and restrictions for every subclass. Well, without this one-to-one relationship, for just Event with several Klasses, I could use FormSet. 
Of course, I could move all TeamRestrictions fields to Klass, but that looks ugly for me.

What should I use for this more complex structure?

Answer (score 1):

You should create for each model a form and do it separately or you can create really sofisticated form which will do it for you.

This form then would have fields as `title` (Event), `title` (Klass), `capacity`, `event`, `age_min` ... so for the relation fields as ForeignKey you will have to use the ChoiceField which will be populated with choices in the `__init__` function and so on. Then it should have good cleaning function so that it would have olny valid data and at the end the `save`. You will have to look if user has selected a field or is creating a new one (such as `Event` for `Klass`) and then process them and link and create everything. But that's not the best solution (even it could be in one step) but it is a choice. It could look great even if you added some javascript.